Best practice to include Torch C++ inside a package
we're creating a ROS2 C++ node which uses Torch and the cpp includes <torch/script.h>.
We'd also like the user to rely on Torch already installed in pytorch. On the nvidia Jetson platforms this is usually installed with wheels inside /home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/.
We're fighting against the CMakeFile.txt in order to accomplish this without editing LD_LIBRARY_PATH manually, if possible.
So far I can create the executable but the .so files are not found at runtime, despite sourcing the workspace setup.bash.
nvidia@nvidia:~/ws$ ldd install/online_traj/lib/online_traj/online_traj
    .....
    libyaml-cpp.so.0.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libyaml-cpp.so.0.6 (0x0000ffff90340000)
    libc10.so => not found
    liblibstatistics_collector.so => /home/nvidia/ros2_humble/install/lib/liblibstatistics_collector.so (0x0000ffff9032a000)
    librcl.so => /home/nvidia/ros2_humble/install/lib/librcl.so (0x0000ffff902e0000)
    libstatistics_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.so => /home/nvidia/ros2_humble/install/lib/libstatistics_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.so (0x0000ffff902cd000)
    libtracetools.so => /home/nvidia/ros2_humble/install/lib/libtracetools.so (0x0000ffff902ba000)
    librmw.so => /home/nvidia/ros2_humble/install/lib/librmw.so (0x0000ffff902a1000)
    libgeometry_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.so => /home/nvidia/ros2_humble/install/lib/libgeometry_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.so (0x0000ffff90288000)
    librcutils.so => /home/nvidia/ros2_humble/install/lib/librcutils.so (0x0000ffff90262000)
    libtorch_cpu.so => not found
    libtorch_cuda.so => not found
    libtorch.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000ffff9007d000)
        .....

According to Compile ROS2 package with pre-compiled shared library a solution is copying the .so files inside install libs, but I don't understand how to dynamically tell to use them at runtime.
This is my current CmakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)
project(online_traj)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
find_package(eigen3_cmake_module REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(yaml_cpp_vendor REQUIRED)
find_package(control_utils REQUIRED)

add_executable(online_traj src/online_traj.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(online_traj Torch rclcpp Eigen3 yaml_cpp_vendor)
target_link_libraries(online_traj "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

target_include_directories(online_traj PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

target_compile_features(online_traj PUBLIC c_std_99 cxx_std_17)  # Require C99 and C++17

ament_export_targets(online_traj HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)

install(FILES 
/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so
/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so
/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so
/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so
DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(TARGETS online_traj
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
  EXPORT online_traj
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
  )

install(DIRECTORY
  config
  DESTINATION
    share/${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_package()

Any suggestion?
With the current CMakeLists.txt /home/nvidia/ws/install/online_traj/lib is included in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH even if the copied .so files are in /home/nvidia/ws/install/online_traj/lib/online_traj.
